# Problem while Placing orders

Tags: orders, shipping-address, edit-order, billing-address

When some one places an order, few other strange products are also getting added along with the selected product. And the address of the customer ends up with some wierd symbols and characters.

The other strange products are not added into the subtotal anyways. Please help me out from this. The strange products are also seen in the invoice and im unable to edit the order to remove them via admin panel. Even if I try to edit the order details and address, again other weird products are getting added

In the following image, the last product in the list is the real order, the other products are added automatically.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply John. Yes, it was the problem of the template. I was able to contact the support and they suggested me to clear few database tables, which contained sample data. 
I truncated these tables which was filled with these "strange " products

sales_flat_order ,
sales_flat_order_address,
sales_flat_order_item,

Now everything is fine

Answer (score 2):

**Observers**

Adding extra items to the cart are likely to be the result of an Observer looking out for one of a few events.

- checkout_cart_product_add_after
- checkout_cart_product_add_before
- checkout_cart_add_product_complete

There could be a few others as well.

Search your custom code local/community for anything that listens to these and may be adding those products into the cart.

**Default Theme**

You should switch the site to your default theme, and see if the problem still exists, it could perhaps be that the theme has some custom functionality that is broken that supports adding perhaps related products into the cart at the same time. If the problem does not exist in the default theme then you will need to inspect what is happening when you add to cart:

- What controller/action is it being submitted to, is this a core file that has been modified, or a third party rewrite of the core?
- Is there extra data being submitted as part of the post request?

**Core Integrity**

Use n98-magerun with the project mess detector to look for changes in the magento core files.

(Mess Detector Module: https://github.com/AOEpeople/mpmd)

(N98-Magerun : https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)

Comment: And check possible extensions like `autoadd` or `advanced promotions` that can add products